# Routing resources issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my invoice app,i have three models associated to each other,but now the problem is how do i add the invoices resource to the clients?

### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :clients , dependent: :destroy
    has_many :invoices , through: :clients
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :invoices
end
```

### Routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :clients do
    resources :invoices
  end
end
```

But each time i try to create a new invoice, I get this error:

"NoMethodError in InvoicesController#create
undefined method `invoices' for nil:NilClass"

### controller's create action:

```
def create
    @client = Client.find_by(id:params[:client_id])
    @invoice = @client.invoices.new(attr_params)
end
```

How do I create an invoice for each client without the error above?

### the edit view:

```
         <%= form_for :invoice , url:{action:"create"} do |f| %>
         <td><%= f.text_field :item_code %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :description %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :qty %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :unit %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field :total %></td>                 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%= f.submit 'preview'%>
        <% end %>
```

### attr_params:

```
private 
  def attr_params
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:item_code,:description,:qty,:unit,:total)
 end
```

### my edit action:

```
@invoice=Invoice.new
@client=Client.find_by(id:params[:id])
```

### Parameters:

(@Siim)

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"HY0lhylr594o7zuTkaO3gf3KJ9kt/2LoqHHW9saQ5hA=",
 "invoice"=>{"item_code"=>"08675",
 "description"=>"food item",
 "qty"=>"6",
 "unit"=>"$123",
 "total"=>"$738"},
 "commit"=>"preview"}
```

def new

```
 @invoice=Invoice.new

 @client=Client.find_by(id:params[:id])

 @user=current_user
```

end

this is my new action,please guys am new to rails,just a month old.

Comment: You will need to provide more info before I can help you. How do your views look like and what are the parameters you're submitting to start with.

Comment: i just updated my code @Siim

Comment: Please also post the parameters that get passed into your create action. To see them, just `puts params.inspect` as the first line in your action and see what is the output.

Answer (score 0):

`Client.invoices` is nil in your create method because it's not receiving an ID in the URL string.

The issue appears to be in your form_for. Check out [the API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for#53-Nested-resources-in-form-for) for how to use `form_for` with nested resources.

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@user, @client, @invoice] do |f| %>
  <%# fields %>
  <%= f.submit 'preview'%>
<% end %>
```

Note that in your `Invoice#new` controller action, you will need to define `@user` and `@client` if you aren't already.

This will generate a correctly formatted-route:

`/users/1/clients/2/invoices`

Which means your `Client.find(params[:client_id])` should get something to build an Invoice off of..

Comment: like i said,am new to rails,started last month,my new action looks like this          def new
    @invoice=Invoice.new
     @client=Client.find_by(id:params[:id])
     @user=current_user
  end

Comment: ...which looks alright to me. Did you try the form above? What were the results?